# Manually adding test suite to nose

Tags: python, testing, nose, nosetests, test-suite

I want to create a test suite manually instead of using test discovery (only in one module, the others should use discovery). I found how I can do this in unittests, but I'm not sure how to transfer that to nose and how it mixes with the discovery. The [nose docs](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/suite.html#nose.suite) don't have examples and I don't understand how I'm supposed to use them. **Could somebody please give me an example?**

Details:
I have test classes where I want to run each method a few times with different parameters. Ideally also changing the test names to something readable. I [tried test generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189699/change-names-of-tests-created-by-nose-test-generators), but they are quite buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Give nosetests the path to your suite, and it will be executed instead of using Nose's test discovery.

This command:

```
nosetests
```

Does automatic test discovery.

These commands:

```
nosetests /path/to/file.py
nosetests /path/to/directory
```

Run the tests in `file.py` and `directory` respectively.

Alternatively, you could start auto discovery in a specific directory:

```
nosetests -w /path/to/directory
```

Check out [nosetests -h for a full list of options](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#options).