# Changing verbose report format for nosetests

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

I am running my tests using `nosetests` in verbose mode:

```
....
test_cache_region (tests.test_sysutil.TestCachedMethodDecorator) ... ok
test_expire (tests.test_sysutil.TestCachedMethodDecorator) ... ok
test_lru (tests.test_sysutil.TestCachedMethodDecorator) ... ok
test_max_capacity (tests.test_sysutil.TestCachedMethodDecorator) ... ok
test_DecimalJSONEncoder (tests.test_util.UtilTestCase) ... ok
test_cdecimal_support (tests.test_util.UtilTestCase) ... ok
test_ceil_with_ndigits (tests.test_util.UtilTestCase) ... ok
test_switch_keyboard (tests.test_util.UtilTestCase) ... ok
...
```

Is there a way to easily change the report format to be like this:

```
...
tests.test_sysutil.TestCachedMethodDecorator.test_lru ... ok
tests.test_sysutil.TestCachedMethodDecorator.test_max_capacity ... ok
tests.test_util.UtilTestCase.test_DecimalJSONEncoder ... ok
tests.test_util.UtilTestCase.test_cdecimal_support ... ok
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override the **str** method of your TestCase class in the following way:

```
def __str__(self):
    return __name__ + "." + self.__class__.__name__ + "." +  self._testMethodName
```

Modify the return string at your will.

Comment: For me that's not an answer. You don't need a TestCase class for Nose. I certainly never use one. Therefore I can't override its methods.

Answer (score 5):

As jorispilot suggested, you could change every single TestCase in your project.  Alternately, you could change nose's behavior by creating [a Nose plugin](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/interface.html) that implements describeTest.  See [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13891931/1309332) for an exact recipe to follow to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth noting that adding doc strings to your unit tests will change the output when you run them...

```
def test_an_empty_string_is_false(self):
    """Test that an empty string == False"""
    self.assertFalse("")
```

will produce `Test that an empty string == False ... ok` when you run nosetests with verbosity.