# Format -v output to make copy/paste runnable in nose tests

Tags: nose

When running nose tests -v you get the following example output by default.

```
test_name dir1.dir2.filename_without_dot_py.TestCaseClassname
```

This contains all the useful information for running a test, but not in a useful copy/paste format to run the test individually.  The ideal output I am trying to create would be

```
dir1/dir2/filename_withoutdot_py.py:TestCaseClassname.test_name
```

Which could then be copied and pasted directly as a nosetest argument

I'm trying to avoid writing my own nose plugin if possible.I realize that there are ways to use sed/awk to suss out the format, but this means anybody who runs a certain set of tests cannot hand me their runnable output without applying the bash output manipulation on top of their test run.

Here is the ugly solution I have for adjusting the output.  It works, but it is both ugly and inconvenient for a process.

```
 nosetests -v | egrep "ERROR|FAIL"sed "s/test\.\([A-Z]\)/testXYZpy:\1/g" | sed "s#\.#/#g" | sed "s/(//g" | sed "s/)//g" | awk '{print $1" "$3"."$2" "$4}' | sed "s/XYZ/./g"
```

I've noticed that site-packages/nose/plugins/xunit.py provides a means to put the output into xml format which is a starting point for an example in accessing the pathname, TestClass and test method.

That said, writing a plugin seems like a lot of work that I'm thinking someone may have already done this, or maybe I am missing something that is known to the community.

Comment: After further searching, I found this stack overflow answer which is helpful.

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459575/changing-verbose-report-format-for-nosetests)