# Python - update current function __name__ attribute programatically

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I'm currently using nose to perform some tests, and when using generators with nose+xunit output you need to set the current function's `__name__` attribute to properly control the name of the test in the xunit output (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21790800/1808861) for example).

Since I don't want to hard-code the name of the function each time like this:

```
def my_function():
  for foo in bar:
    fn = lambda: some_generated_test(foo)
    fn.description = foo.get('name')
    my_function.__name__ = foo.get('name')
    yield fn
```

How can I programatically reference the function and set `__name__`?

I had tried with `sys._getframe()` which yields various properties about the current function (name etc), which I tried to use with `setattr(*something*, "__name__", some_test_name)`, but that didn't work as I couldn't seem to work out which part of `sys._getframe()` references the function.

Comment: Why not just `def some_test_name():`?

Comment: do that outside of function, or write decorator that does that.

Comment: also I think inspect module could help you get name of the function.

Comment: @user2357112 the function contains generators, but nose+xunit use the function name as the test name which isn't accurate when you want the generated test name to be used.

Comment: What's wrong with setting `function.__name__`? How do you want to reference the function? It's not really clear what you want to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution via SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4506081/1808861

A lot more complicated than I expected, but I can now:

```
def my_function():
  for foo in bar:
    fn = lambda: some_generated_test(foo)
    fn.description = foo.get('name')
    setattr(get_func(), "__name__", foo.get('name'))
    yield fn
```

The `xunit` output then contains the generator's data `name` entry.